# KeyError when trying to pull specific API Response Data

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, openweathermap

I want to pull and print dt, temp, weather, humidity and wind speed given the latitude and longitude.

I thought that using data = r.json() would allow me to access the API Response like a dictionary and be able to access/print the elements I want using print(r["   "]), however, I am getting "KeyError: 'dt'"

```
def get_weather(lat,lon):

    import json
    import requests

    r = requests.post('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={}&lon={}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=92d93ccc6ac5587d35d3ccc4479083a1'.format(lat,lon))

    data = r.json()

    dt = data["dt"]
    temp = data["temp"]
    weather = data["weather"]
    humidity = data["humidity"]
    wind_speed = data["wind_speed"]

    print(r["dt"])
    print(r["temp"])
    print(r["weather"])
    print(r["humidity"])
    print(r["wind_speed"])

get_weather(33,44)
```

Answer (score 0):

'dt' is a member of 'current', so you have to access it through 2 keys, you can see this if you print all items in the json like below:

```
def get_weather(lat,lon):

    import json
    import requests

    r = requests.post('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={}&lon={}&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=92d93ccc6ac5587d35d3ccc4479083a1'.format(lat,lon))

    data = r.json()

    for k,v in data.items():
        print(k,v)
    
    current = data['current']
    print(current['dt'])

get_weather(33,44)
```